# How to get next not empty cell in excel

Tags: excel

How do i manage to get the row number of the next not empty cell in relation to the current cell? 
I do not want to use vba!

```
 | A | B |
 1 X   3 (expected result)
 2
 3    
 4 X   7 (expected result) 
 5     
 6     
 7     
 8 X
```

If my formular is located in cell B3, how do i get the row number of the next not empty cell in col A starting from A3?

Comment: Perhaps you should add your expected results to the table you've provided. Also, why are there "x"s in column B?

Comment: Your right, the x in B was just useless.

Comment: Why is there no entry in B8? And rows 3 and 7 are empty, so how do you get those for your expected results?

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in `B1` and copy down:

```
=IF(A1="","",MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((A2:A$100<>0),0),0)+ROW(A1)-1)
```

Change `A$100` as you need